# React Big Calendar views not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

In a minimal configuration for the views, where I set the views prop to an array with one element = "day" I get a row of 9 empty views buttons. I want to use a custom View, but at this point I am stuck just trying to define the views prop.

```
<DnDCalendar
  viewType="Resources"
  localizer={localizer}
  events={events}
  startAccessor="start"
  views="{['day']}"
  endAccessor="end"
  defaultDate={visibleDate}
  draggableAccessor={(event) => true}
  onEventDrop={onEventDrop}
  resourceIdAccessor="resourceId"
  resources={resources}
  resourceTitleAccessor="resourceTitle"
/>
```

Styles included:

```
import './../node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
import './../node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.css'
```

Comment: Did you remember to add the styles as mentioned in the documentation? Look into 'Custom Styling' part of the package documentation.

Comment: By the way, they have starters: https://github.com/arecvlohe/rbc-with-dnd-starter Try it.

Comment: I will add the styles I have to the post, but if I remove the views param altogether, the default views are showing up totally fine, so the problem isn't in styles. It's setting the views manually where it all goes wrong...

Comment: Re starters - my configuration works otherwise fine - with resources and drag-and-drop, it's just the custom views settings that I can't get right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes around the views prop were the mistake. It also requires "view" or "defaultView" prop:

```
<DnDCalendar
 viewType="Resources"                      
 localizer={localizer}
 events={events}           
 startAccessor="start"
 views={['day']}
 defaultView="day"
 endAccessor="end"
 defaultDate={visibleDate}
 draggableAccessor={(event) => true}
 onEventDrop={onEventDrop}
 resourceIdAccessor="resourceId"
 resources={resources}
 resourceTitleAccessor="resourceTitle"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display only the day view in your drag-and-drop calendar, ensure that your **views** prop includes **views={['day']}** and set either the **view** or **defaultView** prop in accordance with **view='day'** or **defaultView='day'**. Here is an example:

```
// Import necessary components and libraries

// ...

<DnDCalendar
  // ... other props
  views={['day']} // Set views prop to an array containing 'day'
  view='day'      // Set the view prop to 'day'
  // ... other props
/>
```